# Master tainted - no pods can be deployed

Tags: kubernetes, taint

In my Kubernetes Dashboard i see, that one node has the Label

```
node-role.kubernetes.io/master:
```

The result is, that all my pods are deployed on the cluster except this node.
( When i increase the replica no pod will be deployed on the master node)
How can i remove the label, i tried the [Kubernetes Trouble Shooting Guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/troubleshooting-kubeadm/)

Following commands did not succeed

```
kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master:-
kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-
kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule-
```

both of them resulted in the message (snip)

```
taint "node-role.kubernetes.io/master:" not found
taint "node-role.kubernetes.io/master:" not found
taint "node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule" not found
```

**Expected output should be:**

- Pods should be deployed on each of the nodes (including the Master)

My Version is `v1.14.1`

Comment: Can you try with node name like `kubectl taint nodes <node1> <key>:NoSchedule-`

Comment: syntax is incorrect. just run below command. that is all you need to do

Comment: kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-

Answer (score 16):

First check the taint present or not with nodename

```
kubectl describe node <nodename> | grep Taints
```

and you will get something like this (master or worker_node)

```
node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule
```

To remove taint from node just run like this (here in my case it is master node)

```
kubectl taint node master node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule-
```

Make sure you add `-` after NoSchedule

Answer (score 3):

Try just `kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-`
without the `:` and without the second command.

The NoSchedule is just a result of the taint, it doesn't need to be removed explicitly.

Comment: According to docs - https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/ `kubectl taint nodes <node1> <key>:NoSchedule-`

Comment: Hi, unfortuenately it is not working 
kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-  
results in  taint "node-role.kubernetes.io/master:" not found , i updated the question

Comment: The `..not found` is to be expected, as it is trying to remove the taint on all nodes that have the master role. 
But you should get `node "<name>" untainted` as well. Can you add the output of `kubectl get nodes -o json | jq .items[].spec.taints` to your post? That should show which taints are still on your nodes.

Answer (score 2):

I had to run `kubectl taint nodes <node-name> node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane-` to remove the taint.

I identified this by first identifying the nodes in the cluster

`kubectl get nodes`.

Then identify if the node is tainted,

`kubectl describe node <node-name> | grep Taints`

Output

```bash
Taints:             node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane:NoSchedule
```

If the node is tainted you can run

`kubectl taint nodes <node-name> node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane-`

Comment: It may be stating the obvious to others, but then run `sudo systemctl restart containerd`

Comment: This was the final piece of my jigsaw. My curl to my apache server works. Now I need to go back and understand how I got here